# How can a restart a loop in an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, collision-detection

I am trying to build a game like space invader (since I only started coding 5 days ago) where if a shoe hits the zombie, the zombie will disappear and reappear at the top of the screen (coming down again). I just can't seem to make the zombie go back to the top (they remain at the lowest point of the animation)

Below is the test for the collision:

```
function zombietestCollision(position1, size1, position2, size2) {
if (((position1.left + size1.width)  > position2.left) &&
    ((position1.top  + size1.height) > position2.top)  &&
    ((position2.left + size2.width)  > position1.left) &&
    ((position2.top  + size2.height) > position1.top)) {

        function loop () {
            movedown($zombie);
            moveup($zombie);
        };
        $(function zombieloop() {
            setInterval( loop, 1 );
        });
}
}
```

I have encompassed this test in my downward movement of the zombie

```
// down movement of the zombies
function movedown($zombie) {      
$zombie.animate({
    'left': 300,
}, {
        duration:5000,
        step:function(){

            $.each($("#zombie"), function(index,zombie) {

                var $zombie = $(zombie);
                var $shoe = $("#shoe");

                var shoeSize = {
                    height: $shoe.height(),
                    width : $shoe.width()
                };

                var zombieSize = {
                    height: $zombie.height(),
                    width : $zombie.width()
                };

                zombietestCollision($shoe.position(), shoeSize, $zombie.position(), zombieSize);


            });
}
```

When I run this, the screen is just blank. What have I done in correctly?
If needed here is the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/JKd9K/7/

Sorry but I am completely new to programming, so it's hard for me to understand which part I did wrong. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with how you're closing functions. Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/JKd9K/2/

Your movedown function should be like this

```
function movedown($zombie) {
    $zombie.animate({
        'left': 300
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        step: function() {
            $.each($("#zombie"), function(index, zombie) {
                var $zombie = $(zombie);
                var $shoe = $("#shoe");
                var shoeSize = {
                    height: $shoe.height(),
                    width: $shoe.width()
                };
                var zombieSize = {
                    height: $zombie.height(),
                    width: $zombie.width()
                };
                zombietestCollision(
                    $shoe.position(),
                    shoeSize,
                    $zombie.position(),
                    zombieSize);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Note that there's a bunch of extra braces at the end.

Comment: oops, yes I structured the code really badly. Thanks James Now that I added those bracket back, the situation I described above remains true - "I just can't seem to make the zombie go back to the top (they remain at the lowest point of the animation)"

Comment: Well there are a few problems in your code. You're trying to use a transition method on your jQuery object which doesn't exist. The transition plugin you've included in not being loaded by the fiddle.

Comment: Oh yes I have it in my code, the fiddle was an older version here is the updated one: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JKd9K/3/)

Comment: Yeah it's in your code but the fiddle cant find it because it's looking for it here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/JKd9K/4/show/jquery.transit.min.js and it's not going to be there because you can't upload additional scripts to fiddle (as far as I know). Also remember to choose your framework on the left beforehand as well because it also can't find your version of jQuery you're trying to include.

Comment: yep updated the framework in http://jsfiddle.net/JKd9K/5/ I just copied my code across to jfiddle to show how my code works right now...

Comment: Well without seeing your live version all I can tell you is that the moveup function is failing due to the lack of the transition plugin. There may be more issues but it's not going to get past that one. If the script is hosted online you can link to it using the 'Add resources' option on the left.

Comment: Ahh thanks James, well I have added the complete js including the images. hopefully that gives a better picture of what I want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/JKd9K/7/

Comment: Well she's going back to the top now? Is that what you wanted or did you want to animate her back to the top?

Comment: Once the shoe hits her (let say half way) she will disappear and reappear at the top - so the animation terminates and restarts the loop again. Hope that make sense and thanks for being so patient lol